# vertex shader Normalization

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl, shader, vertex-shader

I have, maybe, very dumb question.
I need 2 normalized vectors A and B in my vertex shader, I calculated them already on CPU (for other purporses). But to pass it from CPU to shader I had to add one more vec4 attribute (2 * vec2=vec4). I already pass another vec4( vectors C and D), which is this A and B, but multiplied on some koefficients.

My dumb question is - should I pass notmalized vector, or get it from C and D?

```
attribute vec4 dirs;    // .xy = C,   .zw = D

void main(){
...
vec4 norm_dirs = vec4(normalize(dirs.xy), normalize(dirs.zw));    // .xy = A, .zw = B
...
}
```

or

```
attribute vec4 dirs;         // .xy = C,  .zw = D
attribute vec4 norm_dirs;    // .xy = A, .zw = B

void main(){
...
// nothing to do here
...
}
```

I ask this because I worry about throughput GPU memory -> VS. (It increases vec4 attributes count in 1.5-2 times here)

Is there any reason for my worries?

Comment: Vertex data fetches are cheap on the grand scheme of things. The majority of memory bandwidth in GPU goes to fragment operations such as texturing, blending, etc. Normalization, on the other hand, is potentially slow. 12 years ago it was common to avoid normalization through a cubemap texture fetch, these days GPUs have better processing power than memory bandwidth/latency. Since GPU architectures change, the best thing to do is profile your shader on your target hardware... have you done this?

Comment: I have no acess to all of my "target hardware" :))

Comment: Then you have no target. By target hardware, I am referring to at least a ballpark figure regarding the age of the GPU. For instance, if you are targeting OpenGL 2.0 class hardware, then certain optimization approaches might apply that do not apply to 3.0.

Comment: Unless you are doing bleeding edge pbs I doubt it will make any difference. Some 12 odd instructions don't half your fps.